# Retain only the first address in loop vba

Tags: vba, loops

I Have the following piece of code:

```
Dim alpha As String

Sub CopyDataDump()
Dim rSelected As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim bCol As Boolean
Dim bRow As Boolean
Dim vbAnswer As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim text As String
Dim text2 As String
Dim text3 As String
Dim First As String
Dim Second As String
Dim third As String
Dim Fourth As String
Dim ToRange As String
Dim ToBeta As String

    'Set variables
    bCol = False
    bRow = False

    'Prompt user to select cells for formula
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rSelected = Application.InputBox(prompt:= _
                    "Select Range to Copy", _
                    Title:=sTitle & " Creator", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Only run if cells were selected and cancel button was not pressed
    If Not rSelected Is Nothing Then


        'Create string of cell references
        For Each c In rSelected.Cells
        alpha = c.address(bRow, bCol)
    text = c
    First = Left(text, 2)
    text2 = WorksheetFunction.Replace(text, 1, 2, "")
    Second = Left(text2, 2)
    text3 = WorksheetFunction.Replace(text2, 1, 2, "")
    third = Left(text3, 2)
    Fourth = Right(text3, 2)
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(c.address(bRow, bCol)) = Fourth & third & Second & First
        Next
    End If

    ToBeta = Replace(alpha, "A", "f")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    rSelected.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hex_Dump_Flash").Range(ToBeta)

End Sub
```

What I want to do...is retain in alpha the first address and not the last. It always retain the last address.
If I have range A4:A8 I want that alpha to retain A4 and not A8.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting alpha in your For Each with each new c (c becomes the next cell in the range as you loop). You need it outside the loop if to not overwrite. To get only the first cell use

```
alpha = rSelected.Cells(1,1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to detect in the first iteration of your For each loop if 
alpha

has a value. Then you fill it with the first address, else you keep this value through the loop. Can you replace your bloc code by this block below and try it please :

```
'Only run if cells were selected and cancel button was not pressed
    alpha = ""
    If Not rSelected Is Nothing Then
        'Create string of cell references
        For Each c In rSelected.Cells
          If alpha = "" Then alpha = c.Address(bRow, bCol)
             text = c
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Great ;) Glad Glad that it could help you.